# Django search page's url with trailing slash and without

Tags: django, django-1.8

I have a model **Page**

```
class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

When I add a new page through the form I want to be sure that I don't add already added page.

So I do it like this

```
*******
if Page.objects.filter(url=link)
*******
```

But there is a problem. Sometimes the Page instance has an url with trailing slash and sometimes not. The same situation is with given link.

**Situations**

```
link = http://newsru.com
url = http://newsru.com/
```

I could use here `url__startswith` but It will detect all pages with `newsru.com/page1`, `newsru.com/page2` and so on.

`url_contains` won't help

I could use something like this

```
if Page.objects.filter(url=link.strip('/')
```

But url can be with trailing slash.

What's a correct lookup for this situation?

Comment: Why don't you validate urls on the way in, so they are all consistent?

Comment: Do you mean checking the url in `save()` method or some validator?

Comment: In a validation method; presumably they're being entered via some kind of form, you should write a `clean_url()` method to ensure that the value always ends with a slash.

Comment: What if I have a link to some file, let's say http://ftp.com/Django.pdf. Won't it be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django you can use [`Q()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) objects to do OR searches.

```
from django.db.models import Q
link = link.strip('/')
Page.objects.filter(Q(url=link)|Q(url=link+'/')
```

As Daniel suggests in the comments, a better approach would be to normalise the urls as they are added, so that they either all have trailing slashes or none of them do.

Comment: What if I have a link to file? That shouldn't be normalize, should it? However, your approach with Q seems to be the most acceptable in this sutiation.

Comment: Usually static files like pdfs would be handled separately, and served from different URLs. If not, you would have to rethink your normalisation. Perhaps saying all URLs have a trailing slash unless they contain a dot would work.